# Nginx - deploying static page

Tags: nginx

I have a web application deployed on an nginx with the server name `example.com` under the path `var/www/app`.

I added another directory, `var/www/demo` and it only contains a static `.html` page; is it possible to have it like `example.com/demo`?

I have already created a file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` with the following content:

```
server {
    location /demo {
        root /var/www;
    } 
}
```

But it is not working, can someone help?

Comment: This is something really basis and will be explained millions of times. Just a simple google search will bring yout to https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/.

Answer (score 0):

Read http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root

```
server {

root /var/www/;

  location /app {
    index index.html;
  }

  location /demo {
     index index.html;
  }

}
```

Folder structure is

```
/var/www/app/
--- /var/www/app/index.html
/var/www/demo/
--- /var/www/demo/index.html
```

```
$# curl localhost/demo/
<html>
 it works
</html>
```